# request 6 audio input for ubuntu 16/18

Tags: sound, input

I got project for 6 audio input , I looking for using 2 pcs audigy RX
total 4 mic in with 2 line in fucntion, i sure in windows base i can software cortrol the audio input, but did the ubuntu 16/18 support software control 
6 audio input with 2 pcs sound card ? thank you